# error when i inherit from abstract models in django

Tags: django-models, django-1.8

First of all i have been reading a lot and i dont found the answer.

i have a django project and inside that project i have some apps, more especifically

```
DJANGO-PROJECT
    *--------- app_base
    *--------- app_equipment
    *--------- app_customer


then app_base is the app for code that is common to the other apps, in my case i have a models.py file a class who has a class:

from django.db import models
from datetime import date
import project_name.utilies as ut

class BaseModel():   
    status = models.CharField( max_length = 1, choices = ut.STATUS_CHOICES, default = 1 )
    created_date =  models.DateField( default = date.today ) 
    last_modified_date = models.DateField( null = True )
    deleted_date = models.DateField( null = True )
    createdby_id = models.IntegerField( default = 0 )
    modifiedby_id = models.IntegerField( default = 0 )

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

then in app_equipment i have another models.py file and in that file i have the next class:

```
from django.db import models
from app_base.models import BaseModel

class Equipment(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 250 , default="")
    image = models.CharField( max_length = 250 , default="" )
    desc = models.TextField( default="")
    horsepower = models.IntegerField( default = 0 )
    fuelcapacity = models.IntegerField( default = 0 )
    model = models.CharField( max_length = 250 , default="" ) 
    year = models.IntegerField( default = 0 , )
    purchasecost = models.IntegerField( default = 0 )

    class Meta:    
        db_table = "equipment"
```

so equipment extends from BaseModel or that whats i read in django documentation the error is when i want to execute commmand makemigrations i get an error:

**You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to equipment without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py**

and i dont know how to solve it, i'been trying put id fields, and nothing happens, some people say the error is to clear, but what part of the diferents files and app is clear?

the error is solved when i dont inherit the abstract model, but i want to usea all those properties in BaseModel in each table of the others models

thanks in advance guys